# Getting Status Count for an item with many statuses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have the following table variable:

```
DECLARE @DevicesAndStatuses TABLE (Id BIGINT,[Status] INT);

DECLARE @myId BIGINT;
SET @myId = 1;
```

Inside above table I can have thousands of Ids(Id can be repeated) and statuses ranging between 1-50. What is the most efficient way of getting the count of all the statuses for a particular Id?

The traditional method which I have is as follows:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @DevicesAndStatuses WHERE Id = @myId AND [Status] = 1) AS Status1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @DevicesAndStatuses WHERE Id = @myId AND [Status] = 2) AS Status2,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @DevicesAndStatuses WHERE Id = @myId AND [Status] = 3) AS Status3,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @DevicesAndStatuses WHERE Id = @myId AND [Status] = 4) AS Status4,
...
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @DevicesAndStatuses WHERE Id = @myId AND [Status] = 50) AS Status50,

FROM @DevicesAndStatuses WHERE Id = @myId
```

Are there potentially any better solution for getting the count of all the statuses [1-50] for a particular id?

*Final result should be a single row containing 50 columns showing the count(*) of every status as Status1,Status2,...,Status50.*

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion is to use a `group by`:

```
SELECT status, count(*)
FROM @DevicesAndStatuses
WHERE Id = @myId
GROUP BY status;
```

The simplest way to get the information you want, but in multiple rows.

If you want multiple columns, then use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Status1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Status2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Status3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Status4,
       . . .
FROM @DevicesAndStatuses
WHERE Id = @myId
```

Comment: I want a single row of result with 50 columns : status1, status2,...,status50

Comment: And this will do just that....fill in the other 46 columns of statuses and you will be all set.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
SELECT Status, COUNT(*)
FROM @DevicesAndStatuses 
WHERE Id = @myId    
GROUP BY Status
```

This returns all `Status` values for `Id = @myId`, and their count - in one simple statement

Comment: I want the result in count(*) for every status as Status1, status2,..., Status50

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS Id, status, COUNT(*)
  FROM @DevicesAndStatuses
 WHERE Id = @myId
GROUP BY status;
```

or

```
SELECT id AS Id, status, COUNT(*)
  FROM @DevicesAndStatuses
 WHERE Id = @myId
GROUP BY id,status;
```

Comment: Yes Prabhat, I badly missed adding id in Group by. As per my understanding he wants to see both Id and status and the related count. So it should be

Comment: SELECT id AS Id, status, COUNT(*)
    FROM DevicesAndStatuses
     WHERE Id = myId
    GROUP BY id,status;

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a [Dynamic Pivot Query](http://sqlhints.com/tag/dynamic-pivot-column-names/) to achieve this:

I've done it using a generic example but poke me if you need a more specific version. You'll need to use a Temp Table instead of a Table Variable though.

The `STUFF` command is there to remove the `,` from the beginning of the strings.

```
CREATE TABLE #Items
(
    Item INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Status] INT
)

INSERT #Items
(Status)
VALUES
(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(2),(2),(3),(3),(4),(4),(4),(4),(4),(4),(4),(4),(5);


DECLARE @StatusList NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
        @SumSelector NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT @StatusList = CONCAT(@StatusList, N',', QUOTENAME(s.Status)),
       @SumSelector = CONCAT(@SumSelector, N',', N'SUM(', QUOTENAME(s.Status), N') AS Status_', s.Status)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Status] FROM #Items) AS s

SELECT @StatusList = STUFF(@StatusList, 1, 1, N''),
       @SumSelector = STUFF(@SumSelector, 1, 1, N'')

DECLARE @StatusPivotQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT(N'

    SELECT ', @SumSelector, N'
    FROM #Items AS s
    PIVOT
    (
        COUNT(s.[Status])
        FOR s.[Status] IN(', @StatusList, N')
    ) AS pvt ')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @StatusPivotQuery

DROP TABLE #Items
```